# Why can't I see an image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview

I am going to make an image slide. So I used CollectionView.

But I can't see the image. What's the problem?

**ViewController.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "swipe1"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe2"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe3"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe4"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe5")]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = collectionView.frame.size
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

**DataCollectionViewCell.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

class DataCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

}
```

**StoryBoard**

[image]

**CollectionView**

[image]

**cell**

[image]

**Content View**

[image]

**img**

[image]

**Button**

[image]

**view**

[image]

[image]

> the image asset is correct. You have already completed the test.

How can I this problem??

Has anyone solved the same problem as me? Tell me how you solved it.

Comment: did you set the dataSource and delegate for the collectionView?

Comment: @ThePedestrian  After coding, I thought about it later, so I set it up at the end. but The results were the same.

Comment: where is the bottom constraint of imageView?

Comment: @PGDev No image constraints were set at the bottom because there was a button.

Comment: Also, does the images that you specified "swipe1" and others, do they exist in the assets?

Comment: @PGDev Yes, the image asset is correct. You have already completed the test.

Comment: @breakerJohn But you haven't specified the button's top constraint as well.

Comment: give constraint to imageview bottom. You can constraint it to the top of button

Comment: @PGDev But I can see a button. I can't see only the image.

Comment: @PGDev Can I set both the button and the image constraints to zero?

Comment: @breakerJohn I've added the solution as an answer. See if that resolves the issue,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify the **vertical spacing constraint** between the `imageView` and `button`, i.e.

```
button.top = imageView.bottom
```

[image]

Comment: I try to set the top, but only the CollectionView.Bottom.

Comment: Also, the picture is scrolled over. I want to move on to Slide.